# how to sort an integer combined array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this in JS:

```
var a = ["1", "2", "1_10", "1_22", "2_12", "3", "14", "1_15", "3_31", "14_25", "2_18"];
```

and I need to sort it, in order to look like this:

```
["1", "1_10", "1_15", "1_22", "2", "2_12", "2_18", "3", "3_31", "14", "14_25"];
```

I tried using a function like the one in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r7vQP/ but I am getting a wrong answer (["1", "14", "14_25", "1_10", "1_15", "1_22", "2", "2_12", "2_18", "3", "3_31"]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var b = a;
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = b[i].replace('_', '.');
}


b.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });


for (var y = 0; y < b.length; y++) {
    a[y] = b[y].replace('.', '_');
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice - the trick is to keep the values as strings so you don't loose the 0 off the "1.10" but temporarily convert it to float during the sort.

Comment: @Matt Thanks! However I don't quite understand what you meant, I ran the function and the zero in for example `1_10` did not get lost after the sorting.

Comment: Yes, that's why I gave it a +1 :). Compare to one of the other answers present which do lose the 0, as well as early versions of my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function numericSort(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

a.map(function (e) {
    return parseFloat(e.replace("_", "."));
})
.sort(numericSort)
.map(function (e) {
    return e.toString().replace(".", "_");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = ["1", "2", "1_10", "1_22", "2_12", "3", "14", "1_15", "3_31", "14_25", "2_18"];
function sortByFloat (a,b)

    {

    a=parseFloat (a.replace ("_","."));
    b=parseFloat (b.replace ("_","."));
    if (a<b) return -1;
    if (a>b) return 1;
    if (a==b) return 0; 
    }


a.sort (sortByFloat);
```

return a-b would be faster instead of the three  if conditions

Answer (score 0):

```
function to_dot(s) { return s.replace('_','.') }
function from_dot(n) { return n.replace('.','_') }

a.map(to_dot).sort(function(a,b){return a-b}).map(from_dot)
```

> ["1", "1_10", "1_15", "1_22", "2", "2_12", "2_18", "3", "3_31", "14", "14_25"]